# Setting GCP FileStorage and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-filestore

How do you mount the FileStorage to the Kubernetes pod in GCP

I did follow the documentation but the pods still pending

I did:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: <some name>
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /
    server: <filestorage_ip with this format xx.xxx.xxx.xx>
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: <some name>
  namespace: <some name>
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: <some name>
  name: <some name>
  labels:
    app: <some name>
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <some name>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <some name>
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <some name>
        image: gcr.io/somepath/<some name>@sha256:<some hash>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80 
        volumeMounts:
          - name: <some name>
            mountPath: /var/www/html
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: <some name>
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: <some name>
            readOnly: false
```

Running `kubectl -n <some name> describe pods` returns:

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                     From                                                        Message
  ----     ------       ----                    ----                                                        -------
  Warning  FailedMount  23m (x52 over 3h21m)    kubelet, gke-<some name>-default-pool-<some hash>  Unable to mount volumes for pod "<some name>-<some hash>_<some name>(<some hash>)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "<some name>"/"<some name>-<some hash>". list of unmounted volumes=[<some name>-persistent-storage]. list of unattached volumes=[<some name>-persistent-storage default-token-<some hash>]
  Warning  FailedMount  3m5s (x127 over 3h21m)  kubelet, gke-<some name>-default-pool-<some hash>  (combined from similar events): MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "<some name>-storage" : mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/<some path>/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/<some name>-storage --scope -- /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/mounter mount -t nfs <filestorage_ip with this format xx.xxx.xxx.xx>:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/<some hash>/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/<some name>-storage
Output: Running scope as unit: run-<some hash>.scope
Mount failed: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: chroot
Mounting arguments: [/home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs mount -t nfs <filestorage_ip with this format xx.xxx.xxx.xx>:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/<some hash>/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/<some name>-storage]
Output: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <filestorage_ip with this format xx.xxx.xxx.xx>:/
```

It seems that the pod can't access de the IP of the FileStorage service
In the documentation says that needs to be on the same VPC

"Authorized network *
Filestore instances can only be accessed from machines on an authorized VPC network. Select the network from which you need access."

But I don't know how to add the Kubernetes cluster to the VPC

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the output of `gcloud container clusters describe [CLUSTER_NAME]`? Specifically, I want to verify it is in "Alias IP" mode per https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips. This mode is only recently the new default so if your cluster was created a couple weeks ago it is possible it cannot access VPC native services.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

The `PersistentVolume` can't be mount in `path: /`
It needs the "Fileshare properties" field that makes you fill in on the creation
Now works with multiple pods!